# Selenium + Python: Store text in a variable and print

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use `send_keys` to fill a field and in the same time, store this value in a variable. When I run this code, the text of the variable is not printed.

**locators.py**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class CreateNewContractor(object):

  FIRST_NAME = (By.ID, "id_0-first_name")
```

**pages.py**

```
from locators import *

class CreateNewContractor1(Page):


    def fill_contractor(self):

        email = self.find_element(*CreateNewContractor.FIRST_NAME).send_keys("Hello")
        email.text
        print email
```

How can I store and print the text filled in the **email** variable?

Comment: `email.get_attribute('value')`

Comment: @Andersson I tried the option above but the test passed and even so not print the text value.

Answer (score 4):

The `email` variable would get the value `None` - this is what `send_keys()` method returns.

Instead, you can simply keep the text in a variable:

```
text = "hello"
self.find_element(*CreateNewContractor.FIRST_NAME).send_keys(text)
print(text)
```

Or, if you want to actually get the value of the `input`, use `get_attribute()` method:

```
elm = self.find_element(*CreateNewContractor.FIRST_NAME)
elm.send_keys("hello")
print(elm.get_attribute("value"))
```

Comment: I tried all options above but the test passed and even so not print the text value.

Comment: @Rafael are you actually calling the method during the test?

Comment: @Rafael thanks, could it just be the way your runner output the standard out messages? I mean, try putting, say, `print("hello")` after sending keys - do you see it printed?

Comment: I realized now that nothing is printing in my console. See: http://take.ms/kvvx1 and my output http://take.ms/meM62

Comment: For print statements using pytest.. you should execute them with the flag '-s'